# is there a way to differentiate the IOS application launched using custom url and on clicking the application icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I am developing a ios application. When i launch the application it should open the root view. If i am launching the application using custom url from a website, it should initialize with another nib file. Can someone help me with the problem.

Once again thank you for the answers.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, please accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate you have to implement:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

This will be called if your app is opened via URL scheme. In there you can react appropriately.

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: It's downvoting day today it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement open url in app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{

    if (!url)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *URLString = [[url host]stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];      

    return YES;
}
```

Here is a nice link you can follow [link](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/ios-sdk-open-other-app-from-our-app.html?q=open%20url)`